# Can't update npm/yarn package to its latest version

Tags: npm, react-redux, yarnpkg

I am trying to install the latest version of react-redux (7.2.0) with yarn
[image]

but yarn is showing a list of versions which not include the latest version:

[image]

Same with npm:

[image]
[image]

`npm view react-redux`:

[image]

My package.json:

```
{
    "name": "client",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.11",
        "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
        "react": "^16.8.6",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
        "react-hot-loader": "^4.8.4",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
        "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
        "redux": "^4.0.1",
        "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.1.0",
        "redux-saga": "^1.0.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.24.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": [ ">0.2%", "not dead", "not ie <= 11", "not op_mini all" ]
}
```

Does someone knows how can I install it?

Comment: `npm i --save react-redux@7.2.0` and `npm i react-redux@7.2.0` works perfectly fine for me? Version before running command: `7.0.2`, version after running command: `7.2.0`. Have you tried removing the line from `package.json` and running `npm i` or `yarn add` again? What version of `node` and `npm` are you using?

Comment: Yes, it is still showing me error or alternative versions as shown in my screenshots above

Comment: @nopassport1 - I am using npm v6.4.1 & node v10.11.0

Comment: You're out of date on `npm` and `node`. I suggest updating both and trying again

Comment: @nopassport1 - I have updated node & npm (on windows). node is now v12.16.1 & npm is v6.9.0. Still the same issue...

Comment: What does `npm view react-redux` return? Additionally, what does your `package.json` look like? And have you tried removing your `package-lock.json` file and reinstalling all of your dependencies?

Comment: @nopassport1 - I have added a screenshots of my `package.json` and the `npm view react-redux`. I have tried deleting the lock file and re-installing, nothing changed...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208646/discussion-between-nopassport1-and-jank).